# Is there anyway to debug a remote service in app that was not started as part of debug session?

Tags: android, debugging

I want to debug an app not started as part of adb session. So it starts up on BOOT_COMPLETED for example and its just running. Anyway to attach to it at this point and get debug info?

Comment: Is there anyway to guarantee that app is always started for debug purposes even if its started as result of receiving some broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging a process is only a matter of the [debuggable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) flag in the app's manifest. Anything running with debuggable=true can be attached to. You can also DDMS on any such app, read its logs, dump its heap, etc.

Comment: Nice to know its possible.  Could you explain how you would go about attaching to it so you could step thru it. Maybe an app that references its source or something? what type of app would you need?

Comment: How can you determine the port is at?

Comment: Is this specified in manifest too? or can you look up the debug port for the remote app somewhere?

Comment: I have posted this as separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097535/how-do-i-find-debug-port-of-process-if-not-started-from-eclipse