# How do I find Debug Port of Process if not started from eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

App with remote service is deployed with debuggable="true"  but it starts up from BOOT_COMPLETED so how do I now attach a debugger session to it?  What is the debug port and how can I connect from eclipse a debug session to step thru it? I have seen example about remote service but in this case I am not seeing it show up in DDMS view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the Android SDK tools installed then you want to use the `ddms` tool. I have  `/AndroidSDK/tools` in my `$PATH` so can just type:

`> ddms`

in a Terminal and it launches the standalone DDMS GUI tool.

Comment: So I am debugging it now. Only thing is that I miss breaking on service create because service is already started before I press debug on the process.  It does not seem to hit breakpoints on startup. I want to catch service create which is before I manually set the green debug button.